# ASP.NET Entity Framework request SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I need to write this SQL statement in Entity Framework:

```
SELECT 
    SALARIE.MATRICULE, LIEU, UO, UO_RATTACHEMENT, 
    PHOTO.PHOTO, SALARIE.NOM, SALARIE.PRENOM
FROM 
    SALARIE, UNITE_ORG, PHOTO
WHERE
    SALARIE.LIEU = UNITE_ORG.UO
```

I use this method for reading my data :

```
public JsonResult Read()
{
    var nodes = entities.UNITE_ORG.Select(p => new NodeModel { id = p.UO, pid = p.UO_RATTACHEMENT, poste = p.POSTE, img=p.LIB_COMPLET, Fullname=p.RESPONSABLE });
    return Json(new { nodes = nodes }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I need to change this declaration of nodes.

Thank you

Comment: So you simply want the EF equivalent version of the SQL you have posted?

Comment: If that is so, and I am assuming that `SALARIE, UNITE_ORG, PHOTO` these are tables, we need to know the table structure to join them. Also, I STRONGLY suggest you stop doing that as not only may you have ambiguous columns in the return type which will causes errors but you should use `cross join` instead

Comment: SALARIE its a view, and UNITE_ORG, PHOTO these are Tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the equivalent Entity Framework would be the following:

```
var result = (from s in context.SALARIE
              from u in context.UNITE_ORG
              from p in context.PHOTO
              where s.LIEU == u.UO
              select new {
                             MATRICULE = s.MATRICULE,
                             LIEU = s.LIEU,
                             UO = u.UO,
                             UO_RATTACHEMENT = UO_RATTACHEMENT,    // I don't know where this is coming from
                             PHOTO = p.PHOTO,
                             NOM = s.NOM,
                             PRENOM = s.PRENOM
                         }
             );
```

However, this is just a guess from the information you have giving.

Also, like I have stated in my comment, I really think you should stop using the syntax for `cross joins` that you are doing (the `,` seperated syntax)